# C#: How to make an integer rise its value on button click?

Tags: c#, int

I am doing a simple clicker game, i know it is stupid to ask ,but i am still learning ,so my question is how to make the "cost2" integer rise his value +10 every button2 click.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Diamond_Clicker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int clicks = 0;
        private int counter = 1;
        const double factor = 0.95;
        double interval = 1000;
        int cost = 50;
        int cost2 = 500;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdateButton()
        {
            if (clicks >= cost)
                button1.Enabled = true;
            else button1.Enabled = false;


        }

        private void UpdateButton2()
        {
            if (clicks >= cost2)
                button2.Enabled = true;
            else button2.Enabled = false;


        }



        private void myDiamond_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            myDiamond.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Matej Dodevski\\Semos\\C#\\Diamond Clicker\\diamond.png");

        }

        private void myDiamond_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            myDiamond.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Matej Dodevski\\Semos\\C#\\Diamond Clicker\\diamondMouseUp.png");
            clicks++;
            DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
            UpdateButton();
            UpdateButton2();

        }



        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;

            clicks = clicks + 1;
            DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
            UpdateButton();


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            clicks = clicks - cost;
            DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            UpdateButton();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            interval *= factor;
            timer1.Interval = (int)interval;
            cost++;

            label2.Text = "Cost: " + cost.ToString() + "$";



        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clicks = clicks - cost2;
            DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            UpdateButton2();
            button2.Enabled = false;
            interval *= factor;
            timer2.Interval = (int)interval;
            cost2++;

            label4.Text = "Cost: " + cost2.ToString() + "$";
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;

            clicks = clicks + 10;
            DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
            UpdateButton2();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add 10 to an integer?

Comment: Yes but every time i press the button soo if i press it ex. 3 times it should be added 30.

Comment: So put that line in the correct button click event handler method.

Comment: You already have a click function for the button, put the code there!

Comment: Have you consulted with the team that helped you write `clicks = clicks + 10;` in `timer2_Tick`?

Comment: You're likely going to hit a question ban soon if you keep posting poorly received questions here. You have asked several questions in the past day or so, all of which have been simple debugging issues. Please learn how to debug. It's really important, you can't just rely on StackOverflow to do all your work for you.

Comment: I usually chant "Rise, Integer! Rise!"

Comment: My Integer won't rise because it's dead.. Damn Damn Damn...~

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line in your `button2_Click` method

```
cost2 += 10;
```

Comment: Well, if anyone is looking for a good example for [meta] about the quality of questions recently, this is it.

Comment: this was so simple it was not worth posting as a question perhaps the OP needs to understand how to add `+=` will definitely throw him for a loop lol

Comment: Wish people wouldn't answer bad questions. I'm not downvoting, but now this isn't going to get automatically deleted as it very well should be since it's not going to be useful to a soul.

Answer (score 1):

You will simply change `cost2++;` to `cost2 += 10;`